# How do electrons in a conductor physically respond to radio waves?

Tags: electric-current, metals, radio-frequency

If a radio wave hits a thick piece of metal, it's my understanding that the metal will for the most part reflect the wave.  What I'm unclear about is how the electrons flow in a metal that's being impacted by radio waves.  In the case of a metal sphere, do the electrons move toward and away from the side of the sphere absorbing a radio wave?

Comment: You could start by reading this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Radio waves are transverse, i.e., the E-vector is normal to the direction of the radio wave.

Therefore, the electrons will be be moving back and forth along the surface on the side of the sphere being impacted, trying to follow the direction of the E-vector.

However, since the surface of the sphere is curved, the electrons won't be able to move along straight lines and, therefore, it is likely that they will be moving along circular paths formed by the intersection of E-planes of the wave and the sphere.